# For loop returning results twice

Tags: python, pandas

The code below works perfect except for one problem. After running it returns the data for each URL twice instead of once. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong for this to happen?

```
import requests
import csv
from random import choice
import pandas as pd

url_template = "https://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashptstats?College=&Conference=&Country=&DateFrom={date}&DateTo={date}&Division=&DraftPick=&DraftYear=&GameScope=&Height=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&PerMode=Totals&PlayerExperience=&PlayerOrTeam=Player&PlayerPosition=&PtMeasureType=SpeedDistance&Season=2017-18&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&StarterBench=&TeamID=0&VsConference=&VsDivision=&Weight="

lineup_df = pd.DataFrame()

df = pd.read_csv('NBADates.csv')
df.to_dict('series')

url_list=[url_template.format(date=date) for date in df.loc[ : ,"Date"]]

for url in url_list:

    data = requests.get(url, headers={
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0',})

    headers = data.json()['resultSets'][0]['headers']        
    stats = data.json()['resultSets'][0]['rowSet']

    stats_df = pd.DataFrame(stats, columns=headers)
    stats_df=[stats_df.assign(Date2=Date2) for Date2 in df.loc[ : ,"Date2"]]

    # Append to the big dataframe
    lineup_df = lineup_df.append(stats_df, ignore_index=True)

lineup_df.to_csv("Stats.csv")
```

EDIT: Here's the file

```
print(df)

         Date       Date2
0  10%2F17%2F2017  10/17/2017
1  10%2F18%2F2017  10/18/2017
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at `url_list` to see if it contains what you expect?

Comment: Are you sure `NBADates.csv` only has each date once?

Comment: The loop looks fine. I'll bet anything the problem is duplicate dates in the input file.

Comment: File is above. Could the second column be the problem? I think the code worked before I added it.

Comment: What about `print(url_list)`?

Comment: Looks right to me, returns the 2 URL's

Comment: I suspect this is the problem: `[stats_df.assign(Date2=Date2) for Date2 in df.loc[ : ,"Date2"]]` Since `df.loc[:, "Date2"]` returns both dates from the input file, you're creating a dataframe with 2 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
stats_df=[stats_df.assign(Date2=Date2) for Date2 in df.loc[ : ,"Date2"]]
```

This is duplicating the row in `stats_df` for every `Date2` in the input file. I think you just want to get the `Date2` corresponding to the URL you just downloaded, not every `Date2` in `df`. Use the index in `url_list` to access the corresponding row of `df`.

```
import requests
import csv
from random import choice
import pandas as pd

url_template = "https://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashptstats?College=&Conference=&Country=&DateFrom={date}&DateTo={date}&Division=&DraftPick=&DraftYear=&GameScope=&Height=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&PerMode=Totals&PlayerExperience=&PlayerOrTeam=Player&PlayerPosition=&PtMeasureType=SpeedDistance&Season=2017-18&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&StarterBench=&TeamID=0&VsConference=&VsDivision=&Weight="

lineup_df = pd.DataFrame()

df = pd.read_csv('NBADates.csv')
df.to_dict('series')

url_list=[url_template.format(date=date) for date in df.loc[ : ,"Date"]]

for index, url in enumerate(url_list):

    data = requests.get(url, headers={
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0',})

    headers = data.json()['resultSets'][0]['headers']        
    stats = data.json()['resultSets'][0]['rowSet']

    stats_df = pd.DataFrame(stats, columns=headers)
    stats_df = stats_df.assign(Date2=df.loc[index, "Date2"])

    # Append to the big dataframe
    lineup_df = lineup_df.append(stats_df, ignore_index=True)

lineup_df.to_csv("Stats.csv")
```

Comment: stats_df = stats_df.assign(Date2=df[index, "Date2"])

Comment: Response: KeyError: (0, 'Date2')

Comment: I edited it a while ago to say `df.loc[index, "Date2"]`.

Comment: I'm scraping stats for multiple players on a given day, so I need each player to have a column that represents the day the game was played if that makes sense.

Comment: But I'm not really a Pandas expert.

Comment: I know what you're trying to do. But you were looping over ALL the dates, not just the date for those stats.

Comment: If you had 10 dates in the file, you would have gotten each result 10 times.

Comment: That seems to have worked! Thanks a lot, it would've taken me forever to get it right.

Comment: Maybe if you'd looked more carefully you would have seen a different `Date2` in the duplicated results.